# Golang: Best way to evaluate a function once in a specific case

Tags: go, concurrency, locking

Suppose, I have a `Eval` struct and multiple goroutines can call its `Evaluate` method to get the value of the `result` field. Following is the basic structure of code:

```
type Eval struct {
    done  bool
    result interface{}
}

func (e *Eval) Evaluate(f func() interface{}) interface{} {
    if e.done == false {
        e.result = f()
        e.done = true
    }
    return e.result
}
```

As the function passed as argument of `Evaluate` method can take quite some time to execute, so I want to prevent calling that function multiple times. Only the first goroutine to call the `Evaluate` function will actually "evaluate" the value of result. The other goroutines will simply wait for the result field to be ready.

Here is what I came up with:

```
type Eval struct {
    mu    *sync.Mutex
    cond  *sync.Cond // cond uses mu as sync.Locker
    once  *sync.Once
    done  bool
    result interface{}
}

func (e *Eval) Evaluate(f func() interface{}) interface{} {
    go e.once.Do(func() {
        defer e.cond.Broadcast()

        v := f()
        e.mu.Lock()
        e.result = v
        e.done = true
        e.mu.Unlock()
    })

    e.mu.Lock()
    if e.done == false {
        e.cond.Wait()
    }
    v := e.result
    e.mu.Unlock()
    return v
}
```

But I feel like it is an overkill and using a `sync.Mutex` to control access to a variable that will be written once and read many times is not the efficient solution. What is the best and most "golang" way to achieve what I want?

Edit: As mentioned in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63590283/golang-best-way-to-evaluate-a-function-once-in-a-specific-case#comment112448154_63590283), only using `sync.Once` does the job.

Comment: Why not  use `sync.Once` (without a background goroutine doing the call)? It does all this for you.

Comment: actually no, if I use `sync.once` only, then other goroutines will "pass through" the once part, but they still need to wait for `result` field to get evaluated. `Evaluate` function is not just to call the argument function once, it also need to return the value of `result` field.

Comment: No, really, use sync.Once. sync.Once evaluates it once on first call and other calls wait until the first call is finished. From go doc sync.Once.Do: "Because no call to Do returns until the one call to f returns, if f causes
    Do to be called, it will deadlock."

Comment: thanks, thats really helpful. Somehow I missed that part every time I read the documentation.

Comment: You might also be interested in the [singleflight](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/singleflight?tab=doc) package